# Django always trying to connect to Mysql using root user

Tags: django

I created a Dockerfile to build a docker image for a django Project :

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY shop /usr/src/app


RUN python manage.py migrate


EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

And in my settings.py i have this :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER ': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'mydatabase.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PASSWORD': 'adminadmin',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Now when building the image i'm having this error :

**

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user
>   'root'@'172.31.7.119' (using password: YES)")

**

What don't understand is why the error talking about a user "root" while in my settings.py it's clearly set to "admin" ?

Comment: You have a trailing space in the `'USER '` key. So that means that Django does not see this as the username. (change `'USER '` to `'USER'`).

Comment: You're that was the issue, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As **@Willem Van Onsem** mentioned. Remove trailing space in the 'USER ' key.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'xxx.com',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

> Note: DO NOT SHARE your database credentials.